# DevExpress - DevExtreme Chart Label overlapped

Tags: javascript, devexpress, devextreme

I'm using the DevExtreme charts. There's an option resolveLabelOverlapping, when set to `shift` for piechart will solve my problem, but no `shift` for bubble chart.

Is there any solution to let the contents on the labels visible?

[Label overlapped bubble chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXq6R.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the "[customizeLabel](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/?version=15_1#customizeLabel)" callback function for solving your problem. If you set required "[verticalOffset](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/series/label/?version=15_1#verticalOffset)" option for overlapped label you can get the good view for your chart:

```
customizeLabel: function (arg){
        if (arg.valueText === "Instagram") {
            return {
                verticalOffset: -60
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It's what exactly I'm looking for.