# Avoid hiding labels in DevExtreme pie chart

Tags: javascript, label, data-visualization, pie-chart, devextreme

To solve the below problem, I've tried setting [`Offset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34720691/2404470) and [`margin`](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxPieChart/Configuration/margin/?version=16_1)

I've got a pie chart:

[image: proper pie chart label]

which renders labels perfectly.

Sometimes when we change the `datasource` - the labels gets collapsed. And shows only **`...`**

[image: collapsed pie chart label]

My intuition says this happens because of un-necessary white space on the right side.

How do I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. But, currently, this behavior cannot be changed. This is in DevExpress' to-do list: [`dxPieChart` - Provide the `MinAllowedSizePercentage` property](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/T144921.aspx).

When implemented, it should make it possible to improve the resulting chart layout by configuring the minimum allowed Pie size.